# ElasticSearch query_string text search on long field

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following query

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "james",
            "fields": ["briefdescription", "sonumber"]
        }
    }
}
```

I get `"reason": "failed to create query: For input string: \"james\"",`

The problem I think it's `sonumber` is a `long` field, and it fails to search "james" on that field, but if I just use `default_field: "*"`, it doesn't throw the error. Why is that? Does `default_field` skips the incompatible types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's probably the reason, you can also alleviate this using the [`lenient` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-top-level-params) to ignore those errors:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "james",
            "fields": ["briefdescription", "sonumber"],
    -->     "lenient": true
        }
    }
}
```